# Does J have a built-in bitwise xor primitive?

Tags: bitwise-operators, xor, j

I know J has a primitive that works like xor `~:`, but this is really a `not equal to (!=)`

I can make it function like a bitwise xor by saying:`xor =: 4 : '#.((#:x)~:(#:y))'` within a verb definition, but this only works when the binary representations of the numbers are the same length. Is there anything I can do short of making a full-out verb that uses if statements to make the lists of the same size to make a bitwise xor.

In case you're wondering, I'm asking because I want to recreate my Nim-solving program that I got working in Java in J.

Answer (score 2):

J does have a primitive that lets you easily work bitwise. That primary is `b.` and [its documentation](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dbdotn.htm) in the Dictionary gives details. The xor verb you're particularly interested in is `6 b.`

Examples of use can also be found in the Rosetta Code entry, [Bitwise Operations](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations#J).